# Speed of for loop: beyond Big-O notations

Tags: java, for-loop, break

This question has no concern with Big-O notations.

That's actually what surprises me. Consider the code snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        long beg = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int k, l;

        for(l = 0; l < 1000000; l++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 65535; j++) {
                if(pixels[j] == pixels[l])
                    k = j;
                    //j = 70000;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - beg + " ms");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output is:

10 ms

30 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

10 ms

Now, consider the code snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        long beg = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int k, l;

        for(l = 0; l < 1000000; l++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 65535; j++) {
                if(pixels[j] == pixels[l])
                    //k = j;
                    j = 70000;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - beg + " ms");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output is: "164596 ms" and so on. Why?

Comment: Also, note that the JIT will probably remove the two nested loops completely in the first example, since they don't do anything.

Comment: That was my first guess...but, plz explain me how is it applicable on these new codes

Comment: Your first example is assigning a variable to another, so basically a pointer in memory, a very simple/cheap operation. The compiler could probably optimize the for loops making them fast. In the second one, you are actually changing the behaviour of the loops, as well as assigning av large primitive value to a variable. This probably cannot be optimized in the same way.

Comment: That's what is my doubt actually. What and how does the compiler optimize?

Comment: So if first example, according to you, is optimized as "a pointer in memory" operation, are you expecting pixels[0] = j; to be optimized in the same way? It doesn't happen actually.

Comment: Assigning a large primitive value too is not a big deal. Because 'k = 100000000;' doesn't make the code any slower.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting j to 0 every time.

This means you got an infinite loop.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 65535; j++) {
            //break;
            j = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Now tell me how would you explain the phenomenon